# TFS Re-run merge

Tags: tfs

So, In TFS I tried to merge one branch to another - there are a lot of files needing manual merging.

The dialog came up with a list of conflicts. I worked through some and went for a coffee. The screen saver came on. When I came back to my PC the list of conflicts dialog seems to have disappeared and it seems that it's done an 'accept theirs' on all the remaining files.

Is there any way I can force the dialog to come back up? I don't want to have to start again or manually work out what remaining files I need to diff and mess about changing them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is File -> Source Control -> Resume Conflict Resolution.

While in this case the system was working properly and did not actually resolve things "AcceptTheirs" behind your back, it never hurts to be certain.  I wouldn't click Checkin unless you were sure the merged files were in a good state.

Worst case scenario, pend the Merge again in another workspace, then diff the results (sans any manual merges) against the original workspace.  That will tell you which files have & haven't been through some sort of Resolve process that alters file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Press the 'Check In' button. Sounds scary I know if you don't want to check in, but it pops up with a dialog telling you there are unresolved differences and then it shows you the list of conflicting files so you can resume fixing them.

After you've finished going through the list, TFS will tell you that the check-in has been cancelled because there were unresolved differences.